# How to read excel file in pandas with a column with more than one rows within each cell

Tags: python, excel, row, cell

I am trying to read excel file with pandas. But my excel has one column called error has more than one rows within each cell. Example below:

```
Row         Error 
 1          Bank error
            Try again

 2          Limit error
            Cancell
```

When I read this file into python, I only get first rows of the error columns. My dataframe looks like this

```
    Row         Error 
     0          Bank error


     1          Limit error
```

My code below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/My Drive/error.xlsx')
```

How can I fix this and read whole cell to python? Thank you. 
I also added the image of excel of first two rows.
[image: pandas_excel view]

Comment: Is the error column a single column or a bunch of merged columns?

Comment: In case it is a merged column then you need to merge the error column with it's next column(s). By default the `read_excel` reads it as `Unnamed: <n>` where n is column number.

Comment: Actually it is a single column

Answer (score 0):

With specific problems in I/O operations, you are supposed to give us a little sample data(the original excel file with problems). Or we can't get what you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry I added the image. Thanks.